# my tor failed to establish a network connection

Tags: help

It can still connect before yesterday.My system is windows

```
3/3/21, 06:55:12.307 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:55:12.307 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:55:12.307 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:55:12.307 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
3/3/21, 06:55:12.307 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
3/3/21, 06:55:13.650 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
3/3/21, 06:56:37.840 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 6A7551EEE18F78A9813096E82BF84F740D32B911 at 95.217.16.212:443)
3/3/21, 06:56:37.850 [WARN] 9 connections have failed:
3/3/21, 06:56:37.850 [WARN] 9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
3/3/21, 06:56:37.930 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 11; recommendation warn; host 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 at 193.23.244.244:443)
3/3/21, 06:56:37.930 [WARN] 10 connections have failed:
3/3/21, 06:56:37.930 [WARN] 10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
3/3/21, 06:56:37.930 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
3/3/21, 06:56:37.930 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:56:37.112 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
3/3/21, 06:58:10.927 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:58:10.927 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:58:10.927 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:58:10.928 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
3/3/21, 06:58:10.928 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
3/3/21, 06:58:32.576 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 12; recommendation warn; host AC2BEDD0BAC72838EA7E6F113F856C4E8018ACDB at 176.10.107.180:9001)
3/3/21, 06:58:32.576 [WARN] 13 connections have failed:
3/3/21, 06:58:32.576 [WARN] 13 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
3/3/21, 06:58:32.582 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 13; recommendation warn; host F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281 at 131.188.40.189:443)
3/3/21, 06:58:32.582 [WARN] 14 connections have failed:
3/3/21, 06:58:32.582 [WARN] 14 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
3/3/21, 06:58:32.583 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
3/3/21, 06:58:32.583 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
3/3/21, 06:58:32.583 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Have you made any configuration changes to tor? Have you tried using a bridge? Have you tried disabling your VPN if you're using one?

Comment: @Steve I tried using the bridge and disabling VPN, but the problem was not resolved, even though I reinstalled Tor.

Comment: I only get this error if I have accidentally disabled or forgot to enable my VPN, and happened to unset the "Kill internet connection" setting. Had the Tor connection screen open, had been troubleshooting, enabled kill switch and then VPN, Tor instantly completed the connection, configured itself, launched browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded Tor Alpha and used Snowflake,now the problem is solved. In some areas obfs4 or other bridge may have expired.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct then since your solution worked for you.